# Invalid argument exception - Navigation bar, tab bar, UIView

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Class 1 has the following code that generates the exception -

> -(IBAction) searchAllAction: (id) sender {
>     AddDiagSearchController *search = [[AddDiagSearchController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DiagSearch" bundle:nil];
>     [self.navigationController pushViewController:search animated:YES];
>   }

the `pushViewController` part generates the following exception -
`2010-04-14 14:03:31.060 Nav[10314:207] *** -[UIView addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3956a80`

And the class I'm trying to push has the following code. All the connections for IBOutlets were made through the interface builder. It's has a tableView, search text bar and a tabbar at the bottom and I'll be adding this to a UINavigationController.

> @interface AddDiagSearchController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
>     UIBarButtonItem *quickAdd;
>     UIBarButtonItem *searchAll;
>     UITextField *searchTxt;
>   }
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *searchTxt;
>   -(IBAction) searchAllClicked:(id) sender;
>   -(IBAction) quickAddClicked:(id) sender;
>   -(IBAction) searchBtnClicked;
>   -(IBAction) resignResponder: (id) sender;
>   @end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an invalid argument exception, it's unrecognized selector.  You are sending a message meant for a UIControl to a UIView when pushing your AddDiagSearchController, which implies that you probably have a messed up nib file.

Comment: Thanks, deleted and recreated the nib file. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it looks like memory-management issue. I found this [article on CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease) useful in debugging such issues. Note that MallocStackLogging works only on simulator. I would bet that there is issue with **previous** view or controller (it is released too early), not with pushed one.

By the way it seems that you leak memory for `search` as you create and don't `release` nor  `autorelease` it.